# Webpack loader configuration for esm.mjs files in react and typescript project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack

ERROR in ./node_modules/react-hook-form/dist/index.esm.mjs
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (126:22)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

import { useForm,  SubmitHandler } from "react-hook-form";

I am getting this error, when trying to use useForm from the **React Hook Form** package,

please help me out with solution

Answer (score 0):

Use a lower verion that exports .cjs files in dist/ under node_modules
Otherwise, can also update your package.json to include :

```js
"type" : "module",
```

This will enable .mjs files to work (ESModules)

Answer (score 0):

you should add .mjs config details to webpack of react if your version of react-scripts is not 5. So install *react-app-rewired* then create *config-overrides.js* file and add this

```
module.exports = function override(webpackConfig) {
  webpackConfig.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.mjs$/,
    include: /node_modules/,
    type: "javascript/auto"
  });

  return webpackConfig;
}
```

your react scripts in package.json should update to this

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-app-rewired start",
    "build": "react-app-rewired build",
    "test": "react-app-rewired test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
```

other solution is upgrade your react-script to version 5.0.1